# Error code: 429. Description: Too Many Requests: retry after 11

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Как избавиться от этой ошибки? Проигрывает когда много раз используется эта команда. Игровой бот, по этому ставить интервал в `polling` не очень приятно, но даже с ним вылазит эта ошибка, ставил на `5 секунд` - `bot.infinity_polling(none_stop=True, interval=5)`

```py
elif message.text.startswith('каз') or message.text.startswith('Каз') or message.text.startswith('казино') or message.text.startswith('Казино'):
    casino(message)
def casino(message):
    args = message.text.split()

    if len(args) < 2:
        bot.reply_to(message, text='Требуется сообщение в формате "тест (аргумент1) (аргумент2)"')
    else:
        user_id = message.from_user.id

        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
        cur = conn.cursor()

        money = 0
        args_money = message.text.split()[1]
        if args_money:
            try:
                money = int(args_money)
            except ValueError:
                bot.reply_to(message, text='Ошибка')
                return

            cur.execute('SELECT balance FROM users WHERE user_id=("%s")' % user_id)
            users = cur.fetchall()
            conn.commit()

            for user in users:
                if money > user[0]:
                    bot.reply_to(message, text=f'❌ Превышен баланс ❌\n\n Ваш баланс: {user[0]:,}')
                    return

        cur.execute('UPDATE users SET balance=balance-("%s"), casino_games=casino_games+1 WHERE user_id=("%s")' % (
            money, user_id))
        conn.commit()

        msg = bot.send_dice(message.chat.id, '')
        time.sleep(2)
        if msg.dice.value == 1 or msg.dice.value == 22 or msg.dice.value == 43 or msg.dice.value == 64:
            prize = money * 10

            cur.execute('UPDATE users SET balance=balance+("%s") WHERE user_id=("%s")' % (prize, user_id))
            conn.commit()

            cur.execute('SELECT balance FROM users WHERE user_id=("%s")' % user_id)
            users = cur.fetchall()
            conn.commit()

            for user in users:
                bot.reply_to(message, text=f'✅ Вы выиграли {prize:,}\n\n Ваш баланс: {user[0]:,}')
        else:
            cur.execute('SELECT balance FROM users WHERE user_id=("%s")' % user_id)
            users = cur.fetchall()
            conn.commit()

            for user in users:
                bot.reply_to(message, text=f'❌ Вы проиграли {money:,}\n Ваш баланс: {user[0]:,}')

        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Это какой-то не тот интервал. 429 ошибка говорит о том, что бот отправляет слишком много запросов и сервер его блокирует на указанное время. Проверяйте, откуда у вам флуд идет

Comment: @CausonQ с подключением к бд может быть связано?

Comment: единственное что возможно

Comment: Может ли помочь тут webhook?

Comment: Связано с тем, что отправляешь слишком много сообщений

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebHook` подойдёт, если бот не будет работать в общих чатах. По своему опыту говорю. У меня такой бот работал только в ЛС, а на сообщения в общих чатах отвечал с задержкой почти что в сутки. Поэтому обдумав всё и взвесив я бросил `WebHook` и начал писать бот на `Aiogram` - это асинхронная библиотека, так что может быть у меня, да и у тебя что-нибудь да получится.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка значит, что отправляется слишком много запросов - в запросах от телеграмма есть ограничегие `30 сообщений в секунду`. Для предотвращения этого - лучше использовать `WebHook`.